# Is this generic implementation of cache thread safe (c++)?

Tags: c++, templates, thread-safety, c++17

I wrote the following implementation of a generic cache, where `func` will provide the values (compute, read file, etc). **Is it thread safe ?**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

template<class T1, class T2>
class __declspec(dllexport) CacheOf
{
    map<T1, T2> _cache;
    function<T2(T1)> _func;
    mutex CacheMtx;
public:
    CacheOf(function<T2(T1)> func);
    ~CacheOf();
    T2 Get(T1);
    void Clear();
};

template <class T1, class T2>
CacheOf<T1, T2>::CacheOf(std::function<T2(T1)> func)
{
    _func = func;
}

template <class T1, class T2>
CacheOf<T1, T2>::~CacheOf()
{
    _cache.clear();
}

template <class T1, class T2>
auto CacheOf<T1, T2>::Get(T1 key) -> T2
{

    auto it = _cache.find(key);
    T2 value;
    if (it != _cache.end())
    {
        value = it->second;
        return value;
    }
    value = _func(key);
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> cachelock(CacheMtx);
        _cache.insert(pair<T1, T2>(key, value));
    }
    return value;
}

template <class T1, class T2>
auto CacheOf<T1, T2>::Clear() -> void
{
    _cache.clear();
}
```

EDIT: For the context I'll use this class I add this condition:

> for a given key, the value is always the same

Should not I lock only when I `insert` ? Is it fine to read a certain key-value stored in the map while inserting at the same time ? Is is also fine to have 2 threads doing an insert at the same time (so I can avoid the usage of a mutex) ?

My understanding from Butenhoff's book is that we need to use mutex only when we modify the data. Therefore, in a map, due to the fact that for a given key, the pointer to the value will always be the same (thanks to the hash function), therefore if the key exists, I don't need to lock.

Comment: The implementation of map modifies its internal data structures significantly while adding a key. This internal modification is not gated by a mutex or even atomic operations. Have two threads make this sort of modification at the same time will lead to all kinds of problems. Having a thread try to traverse these internal data structures searching for something while they're in the process of being updated will also lead to all kinds of problems. The fact that an add is an idempotent operation in your case is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This implementation is not thread-safe, for multiple reasons.

The first half of `GetOf()` invokes methods of a `std::map`'s instance. None of `std::map`'s methods are thread safe, and the second half of `GetOf()` modifies the `std::map`.

Since the mutex does not protect the first half of `Getof()`, where the aforementioned methods get invoked, this is not thread-safe.

`Clear()` also modifies the `std::map`, without any synchronization/mutex protection, either.

P.S. The invocation of `std::map::clear()` in the destructor is not necessary.

Comment: In c#, there is a `concurrent dictionary`. `Get` always works, but `Set` is implemented by a `tryadd`. Shouldn't I only lock when write ? (I never delete key-value pair, except at clear; or If I want to make it more thread friendly, I could just get rid of `clear`). Do you agree ?

Comment: If you don't have the map locked while you read from it, there's nothing to prevent another thread from locking the lock and writing to the map while your thread is in the middle of reading from it, causing a race condition and invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: C++ is fundamentally different from C# in many ways. None of the containers in the C++ library are thread-safe in any way. Which means that any operation that involves a container must use locking. Hard and fast rule. You can bend the rules just a little bit by using a `std::shared_mutex` and use only a shared lock when only reading the container, but that's as much leeway as you can get.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Let's say the map is only used for reading a key-value or adding a key-value, then I think I can read safely (ie., have consistent result) while adding at the same time. Is it true (or does it depend on the impementation) ? A another situation is: 2+ threads don't find a key and add at the same time (the value is always the same for a given key): can I allow this and still get consistent result after the first insert occured ?

Comment: No, it's not true. There is no other way to state this: C++ containers are not thread-safe by themselves. No exceptions. You will not get a different answer than this, from anyone else (who actually knows C++).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you have a pointer to code source to support your claim, for the sake of having a full understanding ? I still thing otherwise because the hash function is constant, and a certain key-value is unique (it won't be modified). Check out the added details (EDIT).

Comment: C++ is not defined by sample code, but by the C++ specification. Nothing in the C++ specification is thread-safe by default, and you will not find anything in the C++ specification that specified that any method of a `std::map` is thread-safe. The hash function is utterly irrelevant, and doesn't have to do anything with anything else. `std::map` is not thread safe. Even if you never change an existing key in the map, if another thread is modifying the map ***in any way*** you cannot search the map. Even for an existing key. End of story.

Comment: "My understanding from Butenhoff's book is that we need to use mutex only when we modify the data." Correct, and you're modifying the map. Therefore the map must be locked, when it is accessed. The map is one self-contained entity. In most implementations it's a red-black tree. Any insert can rebalance the entire tree, remapping all internal pointers. If another thread is searching that map, for some key, while all the pointers are being ripped from under its feet, hillarity ensues. Boom.

Comment: _"due to the fact that for a given key, the pointer to the value will always be the same (thanks to the hash function), therefore if the key exists, I don't need to lock."_ The key point being the "if the key exists" part. You have to resolve that question by doing a `find`, and `find` is not going to have fun while mutations are taking place. It is true that observing _the value of individual elements_ is much less prone to threading problems, but that's not all that you're doing; you're forgetting all about the map's internal mechanisms that get you to that value.